How do I make transaction instructions to swap on Raydium?
I'm trying to create transaction instructions to swap the raydium of a token. How could I do this?
I would like some example. I'm using python to do this.
    transaction = Transaction()
    transaction.add(
        spl_transfer(
            TokenInstruction.Transfer,
            amount_in,
            user_pc_account,
            pool_pc_account,
            BUYER_PUBLIC_KEY,
            [BUYER_PUBLIC_KEY]
        )
    )

